# OpenCV 2.4 : C API for converting cvMat to IplImage

Tags: opencv, iplimage, opencv-mat

I'm having an YUYV image buffer in cvMat object (snippet shown below). I had to convert this cvMat object to IplImage for color conversion.

```
CvMat cvmat = cvMat(480, 640, CV_8UC2, yuyv_buff);
```

I tried the below options to convert this `cvmat` object to `IplImage` object (src: https://medium.com/@zixuan.wang/mat-cvmat-iplimage-2f9603b43909 ).

```
//cvGetImage()
CvMat M;
IplImage* img = cvCreateImageHeader(M.size(), M.depth(), M.channels());
cvGetImage(&M, img); //Deep Copy

//Or
CvMat M;
IplImage* img = cvGetImage(&M, cvCreateImageHeader(M.size(), M.depth(), M.channels()));

//cvConvert()
CvMat M;
IplImage* img = cvCreateImage(M.size(), M.depth(), M.channels());
cvConvert(&M, img); //Deep Copy
```

But nothing worked. `cvGetImage()`, `cvConvert()` expects `cvArr*` as input. Passing `&cvmat` to them throws exception.

Is there any other way to convert an CvMat object to IplImage object in OpenCV 2.4 ?

**Note:** I cannot use C++ API or any other version of OpenCV. I'm limited to use only OpenCV 2.4

**Edit 1:** My objective is to convert this YUYV buffer to an RGB image object.

Comment: I've never tried to convert backwards, but I suspect that `M.data` will give you the array you need.

Comment: Tried passing M.data, still OpenCV throws exception. `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'. what(): /build/<path>/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2791: error: (-206) in function cvGetImage`

Comment: Instead of creating cvMat, i was able to create an IplImage directly from the yuyv image buffer like below:  `IplImage* frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2); frame->imageData=(char*)yuyv_buffer;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating `cvMat`, I was able to create an `IplImage` directly from the yuyv image buffer like below:

```
IplImage* frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2); 
frame->imageData=(char*)yuyv_buffer;
```